# Postgres - insert and composite foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-key

Say I have a table with the following columns:

```
a:    integer
b:    integer
c:    integer
d:    integer
code: text

(a, b) is a foreign key to another table 1
(c, d) is a foreign key to another table 2
```

Inserting is easy:

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b, c, d, code) VALUES(x1, y1, x2, y2, 'my code')
```

Now, I would like to insert while fetching the values of my composite foreign keys `a,b` and `c,d` in a subquery. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b, c, d, code) VALUES
((SELECT a, b FROM other-table-1 WHERE ...), 
 (SELECT c, d FROM other-table-2 WHERE ...), 'my code')
```

The query above doesn't work ofcourse, but it illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

Another try, but also not working (the sub-query has to return one column):

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b, code)
SELECT (SELECT a, b FROM other-table-1 WHERE ...), 
       (SELECT c, d FROM other-table-2 WHERE ...), 'my code')
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the below syntax to insert records, if 'my code' is always is the static

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b, code)
SELECT a, b, 'my code' FROM other-table WHERE ...
```

If you have multiple table, then you can use syntax like this using CTE

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b, c, d, code)
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT a, b FROM other-table-1 WHERE ...
  ), t2 AS (
    SELECT c, d FROM other-table-2 WHERE ...
  )
select t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t2.d, 'my code' from t1,t2
```

Comment: CTE is new for me, I will try it out! Thanks.

Comment: if you have sample date, then it will be more full-proff solution will be there

Comment: I will try it out with meaninful data. If I stumble upon problems, I will open a new question. Your pointer to CTE helped me a lot here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be structuerd something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b, c, d, code)
SELECT x.a, x.b, y.c, y.d, 'my code' FROM other-table-1 AS x
CROSS JOIN other-table-2 AS y
WHERE ...
```